# I assigned a variable to the value of what is stored at a pointer's address, so why doesn't it change when the initial value does?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

Basically, I just want to know why 'C' doesn't change when 'A' does. I'm guessing that it's because of the hierarchy, but I wanted to confirm and get an explanation as to why...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntCell
{
public:
  explicit IntCell( int initialValue = 0 )
  { storedValue = new int{ initialValue }; }
  
  int read() const
  { return *storedValue; }
  
  void write( int x )
  { *storedValue = x; }
  
private:
  int *storedValue;
};

int main() {
  IntCell a{ 2 };
  IntCell* b = &a;
  IntCell c;
  
  int x = 10000;
  int* y = &x;
  
  cout << *y << endl;
  
  c = *b;
  
  a.write(4);
  cout << a.read() << endl << c.read();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you get and what is the expected output? I get `10000 4 4` which is to be expected, but I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `storedValue` is the same for both instances. Thus `a.write(4);` affects the result of `c.read()`. I think that's what OP means.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and when you change "a", "c" change too.
Also You need to implement a copy constructor and assignment operator.

`IntCell c; // you create a new instance with new memory address.`

[image]

`c = *b; // now this instance point to same memory as "a".`

[image]

`a.write(4); // so when you change "a", "c" change too.`

[image]

Comment: So I'm really new to programming as a whole. What did you do to get that breakdown/ what IDE do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your case, the destructor is missing.

   ```
    ~IntCell(){
     cout<<"deleting...\n";
     delete storedValue;
   }
   ```
2. You are using the implicitly-defined copy assignment. That is why `c = *b;` works. After the copy assignment, `IntCell c` and `IntCell a` both have the member which points to the same location. If `a.write(4)`, `c.read()` will get the same value `4`.